# vi editor for html indenting

Tags: vim, vi

I am doing my development on a redhat linux box having vim of version 7.2. I am doing html, css and javascript development. How can I have the features like indentation feature upon next line, color coding etc.Please suggest me to configure so that my development will be faster and I do not have to copy all the files to my local machine just for indentation.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put these 2 lines in your vimrc for syntax highlighting & filetype specific plugins & indentation rules:

```
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

Besides that, you should also add this option in your vimrc to enable vim to autoindent your code based on context when you press a <CR> :

```
set autoindent
```

Besides that, there could also be several workflows that you could use, netrw a plugin packaged with vim distributions enables you to open & save files over protocols like ftp, rcp, scp, etc. So you could just open remote files directly from your machine and edit them and save.